# WPF custom textblock layout

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF, and I'm wondering if it's possible to create a custom `TextBlock` so that a string can be rendered in a certain way.

So for any given string:

- Wrap the string at a maximum of 32 characters (or any arbitrary length)
- Insert a space between the fourth and fifth character
- Insert a tab between the sixth and seventh character
- Add a vertical pipe at the end of the line, before wrapping.

The list goes on, essentially I'm wondering if I create a custom `TextBlock` inheriting from TextBlock, can I override the default behaviour in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a [`ValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=net-5.0) that transforms the contents of `TextBlock.Text`:

```
public class MyTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(values?[0]))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
            
        var manipulatedString = values[0] as string;
            
        // Do something with the string...
            
        return manipulatedString;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use the converter in your `Window` or `UserControl`:

**MyNamespace.MyWindowClass.xaml.cs**

```
public class MyWindowClass : Window
{
    public MyWindowClass() {}

    public MyTextProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**MyNamespace.MyWindowClass.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyWindowClass"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyTextConverter x:Key="myTextConverterInstance"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- ... -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, 
                     Converter={StaticResource myTextConverterInstance}}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, looks to be what I needed.